# How can I bind Jquery Ajax Json Reponses to a dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to populate Json response from an Ajax call to a drop down and bind Name and UserID in a dropdown. Dropdown values all shows undefined. What I'm doing wrong here? Can you please help?

Dropdown DIV -

```
<div class="row form-group spacer">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    @Html.Label("Recipients")
                                    <select id="commentrecipients" class="dirtyignore" name="commentrecipients"></select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Ajax Call -

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Submission/SecurityGroupsUsersAccessRight",
        data: {
            id: 214
        },
        success: function (data) {

            var s = '<option value="-1">Please Select a Recipient</option>';
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                s += '<option value="' + data[i].UserID + '">' + data[i].Name + '</option>';
            }
            $("#commentrecipients").html(s);
        }
    });
```

Json Response -

```
data = "[{"SecurityGroupID":31,"SecurityGroupName":"Permission Testers","UserID":30,"Name":"Dawn Test'Neil"},{"SecurityGroupID":31,"SecurityGroupName":"Permission Testers","UserID":213,"Name":"Dawn 2 Bates"}]"
```

[image]

Comment: `data = "...` your data is a string, not json.

Comment: Issue was -- not parsing the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding dataType: "json" and remove the "data:" ... something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Submission/SecurityGroupsUsersAccessRight",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (data) {

        var s = '<option value="-1">Please Select a Recipient</option>';
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            s += '<option value="' + data[i].UserID + '">' + data[i].Name + '</option>';
        }
        $("#commentrecipients").html(s);
    }
});
```

Comment: @Partha, you are passing "id: 214" to the service to get the result for matching records. If you remove id: 214, will it not break the functionality?

Comment: @Ayaz - Yes, it will. In real code I'm passing id dynamically rather hardcoding it.

Comment: Removing the calling parameter is irrelevant **and confusing**.  Simply set the `dataType` to the expected format so that your data is converted by jquery instead of you having to do it with `JSON.parse`

Comment: That's a good one! I like that. I removed explicit parsing in code and following your approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the JSON data to get the object and then loop it.

```
ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Submission/SecurityGroupsUsersAccessRight",
        data: {
            id: 214
        },
        success: function (data) {
            let response = JSON.parse(data);
            var s = '<option value="-1">Please Select a Recipient</option>';
            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                s += '<option value="' + response[i].UserID + '">' + response[i].Name + '</option>';
            }
            $("#commentrecipients").html(s);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the camel case property name:-

```
s += '<option value="' + data[i].userID + '">' + data[i].name + '</option>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Submission/SecurityGroupsUsersAccessRight",
    data: {
        id: 214
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data.d, function (i, val) { 
            var s = '<option value="-1">Please Select a Recipient</option>';
            s += '<option value="' + val.UserID + '">' + val.Name + '</option>';
        }
        $("#commentrecipients").html(s);
    }
});
```